# Trouble Converting JSON of Signature-Pad to Paperclip Image (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, canvas, paperclip

What I am trying to do is capture a user's signature in a form on my site. Currently I have successfully added the [signature-pad jQuery plugin](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) to my form and I see the JSON of the canvas signature being sent from the webpage to my server:

```
Started PUT "/participant_user_reg_forms/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-23 19:06:59             -0500
Processing by ParticipantUserRegFormsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CLNbopTBxiLI7WIRNanL9KOtGpAy1
iLjxFGy00nP750=", "participant_user_reg_form"=>{"firm_name"=>"", "user_name"=>"",
"address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "country"=>"", "zip_code"=>"", "email"
=>"", "phone"=>"", "fax"=>"", "question_1"=>"4", "answer_1"=>"", "question_2"=>"
5", "answer_2"=>"", "date_of_birth"=>"", "ssn"=>""}, "output"=>"[{\"lx\":69,\"ly
\":13,\"mx\":69,\"my\":12},{\"lx\":68,\"ly\":12,\"mx\":69,\"my\":13},{\"lx\":67,
\"ly\":12,\"mx\":68,\"my\":12},{\"lx\":66,\"ly\":12,\"mx\":67,\"my\":12},{\"lx\"
:65,\"ly\":12,\"mx\":66,\"my\":12}, ... ETC ...
```

In my controller for the form I capture the "output" parameter and attempt to parse it into an image as follows:

```
if !params[:output].nil?
  @participant_user_reg_form.signature = addSignature(params[:output])
end
...
def addSignature(data)
    require 'open3'
    instructions = JSON.parse(data).map { |h| "line #{h['mx'].to_i},#{h['my'].to_i} #{h['lx'].to_i},#{h['ly'].to_i}" } * ' '
    tempfile = Tempfile.new(["signature", '.png'])
    Open3.popen3("convert -size 298x55 xc:transparent -stroke blue -draw @- #{tempfile.path}") do |input, output, error|
        input.puts instructions
    end
    return tempfile
end
```

I got this chunk of code for converting the JSON to an image from [here](https://gist.github.com/branch14/4258871), which was recommended on the signature-pad site under ruby on rails server-side conversion.

The issue is that when I go and look at the saved signatures (in the default paperclip directory - :rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename) I just find empty png images (png images with 0 bytes of data).

I presume the conversion is not working but I do not know/understand enough about the conversion code to know if it is functioning properly. Alternatively, I am open to saving the signature generated on the canvas in other ways (such as with chunky_png) but I have been unable to find any good information/code that describes or shows how to do that conversion from canvas to paperclip image.